# makefile - check variable is one of them

Tags: makefile

In the makefile of my project, there's code which is similiar to this:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), rebuild)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), rerun)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), distclean)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), mostlyclean)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), dep-clean)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), tools)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), tools-clean)
include $(DEPENDENCIES)
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
endif
```

It's too tired.. Is there any way to make it more simple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@keltar's answer works but `findstring` is not really the best choice since it succeeds even for substrings.  Better is to use `filter` which is exact word matches:

```
GOALS := rebuild rerun distclean clean mostlyclean dep-clean tools tools-clean

ifeq (,$(filter $(GOALS),$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  include $(DEPENDENCIES)
endif
```

Comment: +1, didn't knew about `filter` but suspected it should have something like that

Comment: A very good approach. I have to add that the above solution only works for me when adding a space in between ifeq and the opening bracket. Otherwise I#d get the _missing separator_ error

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that

```
GOALS:=rebuild rerun distclean clean mostlyclean dep-clean tools tools-clean
ifneq ($(findstring $(MAKECMDGOALS), $(GOALS)),)
include $(DEPENDENCIES)
endif
```

But this would have problem if you specify multiple goals at once (e.g. `make clean distclean`).

However, do you need that at the first place? Why not use `-include` instead, which will include files but will not fail even if it can't?

Comment: Note the idea behind avoiding `include` is not related to failing, it's so that the included file isn't rebuilt: most likely the dependencies are constructed by compiling the code and you don't want to do that if you are running `clean`.